# Google play app signing process certificates

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

I am trying to understand the signing process with the Play App Signing.
Hence couple of questions.

1. I am using google maps API, why I need to add SHA-1 certificate fingerprint of App signing key certificate on the console? Why I cant use that SHA 1 which is generated on my pc locally?
2. What I need to do with the provate_key.pepk that I generated from release?
3. What is the purpose of deployment_cert.der?
4. What is the purpose of upload_cert.der?

Can you please explain me the correct process of signing an app and how to use it?

Also [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756#create&zippy=%2Cexisting-apps)

Existing apps->Step 2->5 Syas: Select the export and upload option that best suits your release process and upload an existing app signing key.

I do not see an option for upload an existing app signing key...

Comment: Interested to further understand on the process as well. Though I've been signing my app with keystores generated on local machine via Android Studio. Have never upload any of my keystore/cert to the portal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The app signing process in Play store is demonstrated below,

[image]

Google Play signing uses two keys.

- Upload key
- App signing key

#### Upload Key

> TL;DR: Google use this key to identify the uploader of the apk/bundle

This key is used to sign the apk/bundle when uploading to the Play Store. This key let Android know the app updates are authentic and comes from the original author.

`upload_cert.der` is the public key for the Upload key.

#### App Signing Key

This key is used to sign the APKs that are installed in the user's device. You can have Google manage the key

`deployment_cert.der` is the public key of the app signing key.

So answering your questions,

1. if your device is running app signed with `upload key` (developer key), the fingerprints in API console should match with the `upload key`, vice versa if the app in your device is signed with `App Signing key`, you need to have the fingerprints of the same. Commonly the signed apks/bundles built from android studio are signed with the `upload key` you choose. The app installs from the Play Store uses `App Signing Key`.
2. Keep it safe, this is required for Google to identify the author when pushing updates.
3. See the `App Signing Key` part
4. See the `Upload Key` part

Comment: What about app that is not signed by neither `upload key` nor `App Signing Key` but using local keystores? This is 2 differently things from what you have explained right?

Comment: @TommyLeong with Google Play signing these two keys are applicable. For  debugging, the required signing keys are auto generated at `$HOME/.android/debug.keystore` which is insecure and just meet the purpose of debugging (you dont have to enter the password, username and related stuff each time you build your code).  Google Play Store **DOES NOT** accepts apps signed with the debug certificate for publishing in their store.

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy do you happen to know - if I allow Google to sign my binary, is there any way for me to know package signature? I use context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES) to get a signature and decrypt some data, which previously encrypted with it. But if I allo Google to sign - will my security fail?

Comment: @Tertium with encrypting questions is often question of trust. If you encrypt data with a key only Google manages and knows,  meaning that Google knows both public and private key, Google can decrypt your data and all others can decrypt, if they break the key, meaning to calculate right private key.  If you use use your own key, question is if someone can break your key including Google. If you trust that Google will never do things like using users keys in things they should not, you can use Googles keys.